# Execution javascript function inside handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js, helper

I try to execute JS function in hbs for displaying html depend on data from MongoDB. And now i cant put handlebars inside handlebars

```
      {{#if_eq author '{{ ../user._id }}' }}
         <a href="/article/{{ slug }}" class="more" id="read">читать больше</a>
        <form action="/article/{{ this._id }}?_method=DELETE" method="post" class="more">
       <button type="submit" name="button">удалить</button>
     </form>
   {{/if_eq}}
```

and:

```
hbs.handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
    if (a == b) {
        return opts.fn(this);
    } else {
        return opts.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

It doesnt work. How handlebars-helper can help in this situation?

I also tried to execute function and put there variable:

```
      hbs.handlebars.registerHelper('isApply', function(req, opts) {
  let user =  req.user.name;
    if (this.name === 'user') {
       console.log(user);
        return opts.fn(this);
    } else {
        return opts.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

and do this in my template:

```
   {{#isApply}}
         <a href="/article/{{ slug }}" class="more" id="read">читать больше</a>
        <form action="/article/{{ this._id }}?_method=DELETE" method="post" class="more">
       <button type="submit" name="button">удалить</button>
     </form>
   {{/isApply}}
```

But it also doesnt work, cuz user: undefined.

Please can you help to find a solution of this issue?